# An array is being assigned a dynamic number of values causing an exception. How do I bypass this?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, try-catch

```
try
{
    while (true) //cant verify against port.readline == null directly
    {
        output = Convert.ToString(port.ReadLine()); //causes exception
        lines++;

        if (lines > 5)
        {
            holder = output.Split(delimiters);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception) { }


MessageBox.Show("Unreachable!");
```

So basically I either have an infinite loop (without the try catch), or an exception which stops the code. Am I missing something obvious? I need to execute more code after this point.

Comment: ah sorry its a SerialPort,
`port = new SerialPort("COM6", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);`

Comment: Why not move the try/catch inside the while loop?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know serial ports but based on the code you've provided:

```
var portValue = port.ReadLine();
if (portValue == null)
    break; // *** This is the magic you're looking for ***

output = Convert.ToString(portValue);
```

Using a `break` statement will kick you out of your infinite loop.

Comment: The thing is that `ReadLine` is a blocking method that does not return until a newline character is read, or until a TimeoutException is thrown (if a `ReadTimeout` has been set). Which means that the result of the operation should never be null; instead, the proper way would be to catch and process TimeoutExceptions separately and adjust the timeout value accordingly (should be 500ms by default). Edit: [ReadLine docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline.aspx)